# Handling libraries in correct way

Tags: servlets, intellij-idea, jboss

I'm new to Intellij. I've created a maven project and I'm playing around adding different kind of frameworks to the project. I'm using JBoss wildfly.

I'm having problem with the web application framework. Its creating web.xml and all the necessary folders. But when I try to create a Servlet I get an error saying that "javax.servlet.http" does not exist upon trying to compile the application.

I'm pretty sure the JBoss Wildfly application has the serlvet api but I'm not sure how to add all those libraries to the project. I could add them manually but I don't think that is the correct way to do it. All the necessary web application api should be available by default give that you have chosen the right frameworks.

What am i doing wrong?

Edit: Ok I've managed to find all the API inside of the wildfly folder. But It feels very clunky to be forced to add servlet API manually. Intellij adds all the api for web application when you create a project and add application server - > Wildfly. But you when you create a maven project and add web application framework servlet api is not added to project libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You should configure your dependencies using Maven if you have a maven project. IntelliJ only adds libraries for projects that use IDEA to build (because it has to download the jars, build libraries, and get that all into the class path).

Since maven is your build tool, you are responsible for setting up the dependencies in your pom.

Answer (score 0):

As said in sylvanaay's answer you have to add servlet-api in your pom but it should be in provided scope as follows.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

If you add the library mannualy in Intellij IDEA the build may fail when you do maven build.